# Deny OPTIONS stops all type of requests

Tags: .net, iis, request, requestfiltering

I am following these [instructions](https://improveandrepeat.com/2019/12/how-to-remove-the-options-method-in-iis-8-5/) to add request filtering. I want to avoid OPTIONS verb but when I add it as 'deny' verb inside IIS 10, IIS is not serving any request with `get, put, post` or `delete`.
[image]

As you can see, a `get` request is also not being served at all....

Comment: You can try to enable get, put, post and delete on the iis server -> .NET Authorization Rules.

Comment: I did that first @samwu. I only allowed get, put , post and delete, but it still was sending options request

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays browsers are following CORS rules to access web server resources,

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

So, your blocking of `OPTIONS` requests literally break the whole CORS workflows, and no doubt nothing more is being requested/served.